# Node.js send file to client

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Hello there I have been trying to send a file from node.js to the client.

My code works however when the client goes to the specified url (`/helloworld/hello.js/test`) it streams the file.

Accessing it from Google Chrome makes the file (.mp3) play in a player.

My goal is to have the client's browser download the file and ask the client where he wants to store it, not stream it on the website.

```js
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    switch (req.url) {
        case '/helloworld/hello.js/test':

            var filePath = path.join(__dirname, '/files/output.mp3');
            var stat = fileSystem.statSync(filePath);

            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
                'Content-Length': stat.size
            });

            var readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(filePath);
            // We replaced all the event handlers with a simple call to readStream.pipe()
            readStream.on('open', function() {
                // This just pipes the read stream to the response object (which goes to the client)
                readStream.pipe(res);
            });

            readStream.on('error', function(err) {
                res.end(err);
            });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to set some header flags;

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
    'Content-Length': stat.size,
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=your_file_name'
});
```

For replacing streaming with download;

```
var file = fs.readFile(filePath, 'binary');

res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg');
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=your_file_name');
res.write(file, 'binary');
res.end();
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but now it only downloads 4mb of the file now the whole file which is about 6mb.

Comment: Have you checked the file content? Everything is inside?

Comment: It is very bad to user `readFileSync` in the request handler since Node.js is single-threaded. So if you have two requests to that url, the second one will wait till the first one finishes it's operation. On localhost you may not notice that anything is wrong, but on a production server with 1,000 requests per second there will be delays. Use [`readFile`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) with a callback instead

Comment: Thanks @Zub for your warning. That was just an example but you are absolutely right. So, I have updated my code just to prevent such cases you described

Comment: Could [res.download()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download) be used instead?

Comment: I tried to piece together the code from the original question and this answer but get error: `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

Answer (score 19):

Below solution is for Express JS.

```
app.get('/download', (req, res) => res.download('./file.pdf'))
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I just tested this an it seems to be working just fine for a Node Express server. If something is wrong with this answer, please provide feedback so everyone knows why it should not be used.

Comment: @StevenVerheyen : This works but somehow someone downvoted it. Don't know why

Comment: yes, it works, thanks buddy, here is the [reference](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download)

Comment: Probably because the question wasn't asking for Express?

Answer (score -1):

```
response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
     modification-date="date_object",
    'Content-Disposition: attachment; 
     filename=output.mp3' 

  });
```

you need to works on your header part i.e. your content-Disposition part, only then it will allow you to get the data out. read more about [content Disposition](http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html)

Comment: @MaratArguinbaev - did you make any progress with this and get it to work?  I know its an old thread, but I'm trying to do something similar.  Qnother question is did you stick with NODE.js or eventually move to another framework / solution for websockets?  Thanks!