# Need help writing json data to json file in a GET function for a REST api

Tags: javascript, json, rest, api, server

I'm really new to json and am having trouble with writing to a file. I'm trying to write a GET function in a REST api that will get information from a url and save it to a json file. There are 3 components of the url I'm trying to get. The function is successfully getting the information but I'm not sure how to save it to the json file. This is my code below.

```
app.get('/user', function(req, res){
    response = {
        id : req.query.id,
        hash : req.query.hash,
        size : req.query.size
        };
    console.log(response);
    //var fs = require('fs');
    //var obj = JSON.parse(fs.writeFileSync('userdata.json', 'utf8'));
    //res.status(200).json(obj);
    //res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

The code prints to the terminal correctly in json format but I'm having trouble saving the data. Thanks for the help. It's much appreciated.

Comment: Where I have commented is what I'm doing wrong

Comment: The second argument to writeFileSync() is the actual data you want to write, it also only returns `undefined` so nothing to `parse()`.

Comment: Do you want to write that json data into `.json` file and save?

Comment: yes specifically userdata.json

Comment: I am passing the data in as http://localhost:3000/user?id=3&hash=qwerty&size=47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fs.writeFile('jsonData.json', JSON.stringify(response), function(err) {
               if (err) {
                    console.log('Error found : ' + err.message);    
               } else {
                    //do the rest
               }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean in "do the rest" and just to be clear I'm trying to save the "responce" into the file.json

Comment: fs.writeFile() is saving your response into `.json` file. `err` parameter will give if any error in that process. if code reached to `else` condition that means your file was saved correctly. you can check your root directory. If you want to send your file to browser side, check this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578208/node-js-send-file-to-client]

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using 2 methods

1. by creating manual json file and triggering click event:

   ```
   function download() {
       var fileContents=JSON.stringify(jsonObject, null, 2);
       var fileName= "filejson.json";

       var pp = document.createElement('a');
       pp.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + 
       encodeURIComponent(fileContents));
       pp.setAttribute('download', fileName);
       pp.click();
   }
   setTimeout(function() {download()}, 500);
   ```
2. using write file stream:

   ```
   obj = JSON.parse(data); //now its an object
   json = JSON.stringify(obj); //convert it back to json
   fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', json, 'utf8', function(err) {
       console.log(err); // if there is an error
   });
   ```