# Nodejs path in local server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, path

I have a pc that hosts my web app. When I access some export methods in another pc, The exported files are saved on to the server pc. I want the file to be saved on the pc that I'm currently using. So when I click the export button in the current pc, I want it to be saved in my 'Downloads' folder and not in the 'Downloads' folder of the server pc. How do I do that? I'm relatively new to node.js. Here is my code

```
const exportExcel = (arrayData, name) => {
let model = mongoXlsx.buildDynamicModel(arrayData);
let options = {
    save: true,
    sheetName: [],
    fileName: `${name}${getCurrentDateTime()}.xlsx`,
    path: `C:\\Users\\${process.env.USERNAME}\\Downloads`,
    defaultSheetName: "worksheet"
};
mongoXlsx.mongoData2Xlsx(arrayData, model, options, function(err, data) {
    console.log("File saved");
});
};
```

Comment: But NodeJS runs in backend. As far as I know, you can't just save a file in the client device. You can send the file to your front-end (client) and, there, download it to the client device.

Comment: Hey @AleSanchez what do you think is the best approach to this? Shall I change my path decleration into a file dialog or something?

Comment: Take the saved file, read it and send it to client as response to the request made by click on web app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578208/node-js-send-file-to-client. Another better option is to create export file on the fly, and send it without storing it on server, if file is not going to be too large.

Comment: In my opinion, the _big problem_ here is that you are attempting to do that "save-file logic" in the backend and that's not possible (well, it's possible if you want to save the file in the server, but this is not that case). You have to send the file to the front-end and, there, do **all the logic** to save it (not only asking for the path, but also retrieving the file from the server and saving it).